# Location tracking with firebase in ios

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geolocation, location

I am working on an iOS application like Uber Eats. In this application, I need to track the location of Rider, who deliver the food from restaurant to customer. when as a customer someone order the food, I need to show the location of Rider to customer on the map in the application.

How can I use the firebase to get the latitude and longitude to show Rider location on map rather than using web service 
which I will have to call again and again to get updated location of rider to show on map? is it possible to get location coordinates from firebase in iOS application without calling a method again and again so that location could be updated automatically as soon as Rider location update on firebase?

Comment: Yes. You can use

Comment: how can I use the firebase for this purpose in my iOS application?

Comment: Are you updating rider location to firebase?

Comment: yes, i am updating Rider location to firebase

Comment: Add observer from customer app to that channel

Comment: Can you please elaborate how can I add this observer? Do I need to use Firebase Realtime Database for this purpose?